# Endpoint with FormDataContentDisposition param - required fields

Tags: java, rest, jersey, multipartform-data, content-disposition

I use Jersey 1.19. I have REST endpoint which consumes MULTIPART_FORM_DATA:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{id}/image")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response putImages(
        @PathParam("id") Long id,
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fullImageStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fullImageDetails) {

}
```

Currently default FormDataContentDisposition configuration requires file name. How to configure FormDataContentDisposition to make fields optional or mandatory?

Comment: You can use `FormDataMultiPart` as a parameter to grab the entire form and then extract your parameters from that object.